# Pyglet Screen Flickering when Keys are Pressed

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

When I run my demo program, the keyboard input works perfectly, but when I press a key on the keyboard, the screen flickers. It happens at random, and not just when I press the key, but also on the release.

Here is my render function:

```
@self.win.event
    def on_draw():
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) #clear backbuffer and z-buffer
        #calculate view matrix
        viewMatrix = self.lookat(self.cameraPos, self.cameraTarget, self.cameraUp)
        texnum = -1 #set texture to default
        shader = '' #set shader to default
        modelMatrixNum = -1 #set model matrix to default
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) #enable textures
        for render in self.renderList: #loop through poly lists in renderList
            try:
                if render['tex'] != texnum: #if this poly list is using a different texture,
                    texnum = render['tex'] #bind it, and reset default
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texnum)
            except KeyError: #but if it doesn't have a texture
                pass #just use the last one
            try:
                if shader != render['shd']: #if this poly list is using a different shader,
                    shader = render['shd']
                    self.shaders[shader].UseProgram() #change shader
                    self.shaders[shader].SetViewMatrix(viewMatrix)
                    self.shaders[shader].SetProjectionMatrix(self.projectionMatrix)
                    self.shaders[shader].SetColorMatrix(self.colorMatrix)
            except KeyError: #but if it doesn't have a shader
                pass #just use the last one

            #now, calculate matrices that vary for each polygon and write them
            try:
                modelMatrix = render['mod'] #see if this polygon has any special modeling matrix
            except KeyError:
                #if not, just use the identity matrix
                modelMatrix = np.identity(4)
            # Set uniforms in shader program
            self.shaders[shader].SetModelMatrix(modelMatrix)
            # Write matrices
            self.shaders[shader].WriteMatrices()

            render['vrt'].draw(render['prm']) #actually draw polygon
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        self.renderList = [] #clear renderList for next loop
```

These are my input functions (all they do is display the input VKID):

```
@self.win.event
    def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
        print symbol

    @self.win.event
    def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
        print symbol
```

How do I fix this? Has anyone else had this problem?

EDIT: I figured it out. Changing `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0/self.FPS)` to `pyglet.clock.schedule(update)` runs `update` at 60 FPS, but it you schedule an interval for it, then the screen flickers when you press the keys.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem if you try the following code: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/a67475773b39a8209b2841d9b08922ca (Note: Add `self.shaders` and `self.renderList = []` etc in `__init__` and elsewhere)

Comment: I changed it like you said, but now 1) it only shows a white screen (the music and sound still works, though) and 2) when you click the close button, it cleans up and exits, but the window stays open.